# Use openpyxl to edit a Excel2007 file (.xlsx) without changing its own styles?

Tags: python, excel-2007, openpyxl

I have a .xlsx file to edit, I found [openpyxl](http://packages.python.org/openpyxl/) could manipulate Excel 2007 files.
I only want to change the value in some cells and leave other settings unchanged.

But after I went through the [Documentation](http://packages.python.org/openpyxl/index.html), I cannot find the examples to edit a existing file. It only demostrated reading a .xlsx file and writing to a new one.

I tried below way to edit an existing file, but after I saved it, the styles in the file has been removed( like fonts, colors):

```
from openpyxl.reader.excel import load_workbook
wb=load_workbook(r'd:\foo1.xlsx')
ws=wb.get_sheet_by_name('Bar')
ws.cell('A1').value= 'new_value'
# save the workbook to a new file to finish the editing
# but the style settings has been removed (such like font, color) in the new file
wb.save(r'd:\foo2.xlsx')
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Now openpyxl cannot handle styles good enough, so I tried using pywin32 COM and got the solution.
Here is a good [python-excel-mini-cookbook](https://pythonexcels.com/python/2009/10/05/python-excel-mini-cookbook) to use pywin32 COM for Excel

Comment: Nice link! Should it ever go offline, here's a gist with the same content: https://gist.github.com/airstrike/5469478

Answer (score 1):

Styles aren't fully supported yet in openpyxl.  Make sure you're using the [latest version](https://bitbucket.org/ericgazoni/openpyxl/) (1.5.3 as of now), as it recently improved its style capabilities.

The xlwt has more complete formatting for .xls files, but doesn't support xlsx as of yet.

Comment: Yes, I am using v1.5.3, so it seems that there is no good way right now. Would 'COM with pywin32' work?

Comment: COM supposedly works - and uses office's native interface. I haven't tried it though as it only works on windows.  Good luck with it!

Comment: Is the styles able keep after updating column with new version?

Comment: @conandor - yes.  The less common named styles still aren't supported, but as of openpyxl 2.1, the majority of your style information is preserved (and even editable!), including row/col styles and conditional formatting.