# Openpyxl , how to preserve .xlsx file style which was before , after saving it with openpyxl .save() function?

Tags: excel, openpyxl

*I have an issue with openpyxl library.*

**Problem:**

When I used xlwt, opened an .xls file, and wrote some cells in there, the styles of cells I didn't touch remained the same. But now I have to work with xlsx documents, so I chose openpyxl for this. But after saving it with a .save function, it completely strips the style of a document, even the cells I didn't touch at all.

**Any suggestions on how I can preserve the style?**

Comment: This hasn't been an issue in openpyxl since version 2.

Comment: I see the same problem with latest openpyxl v 2.3.2

Answer (score 3):

I'm having this exact problem, apparently there is no good way to preserve the styles in openpyxl, see
[Use openpyxl to edit a Excel2007 file (.xlsx) without changing its own styles?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6772438/use-openpyxl-to-edit-a-excel2007-file-xlsx-without-changing-its-own-styles)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think openpyxl solved this issue yet. You can try pywin32 to directly interact with windows API with Excel, you can do everything there you want.