# How to write/update data into cells of existing XLSX workbook using xlsxwriter in python

Tags: python, excel, xlsxwriter

I am able to write into new xlsx workbook using

```
import xlsxwriter  
def write_column(csvlist):
    workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook("filename.xlsx",{'strings_to_numbers': True})
    worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
    row = 0
    col = 0
    for i in csvlist:
        worksheet.write(col,row, i)
        col += 1

    workbook.close()
```

but couldn't find the way to write in an existing workbook.
Please help me to write/update cells in existing workbook using xlswriter or any alternative.

Comment: I think openpxyl is the only python library that claims to both read and write files. I haven't used it, but the xlswriter docs mention it. (related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18002133/xlsxwriter-is-there-a-way-to-open-an-existing-worksheet-in-my-workbook )

Comment: Also Xlwings and win32com.

Answer (score 70):

Quote from `xlsxwriter` module [documentation](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/introduction.html):

> This module cannot be used to modify or write to an existing Excel
>   XLSX file.

If you want to modify existing `xlsx` workbook, consider using [openpyxl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.org) module.

See also:

- [Modify an existing Excel file using Openpyxl in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13381384/modify-an-existing-excel-file-using-openpyxl-in-python?rq=1)
- [Use openpyxl to edit a Excel2007 file (.xlsx) without changing its own styles?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6772438/use-openpyxl-to-edit-a-excel2007-file-xlsx-without-changing-its-own-styles)

Comment: openpyxl can read existing excel files and write data back to it. However, if your excel sheet/workbook has charts, those charts will be lost.

Answer (score 24):

you can use this code to open (test.xlsx) file and modify A1 cell and then save it with a new name

```
import openpyxl
xfile = openpyxl.load_workbook('test.xlsx')

sheet = xfile.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')
sheet['A1'] = 'hello world'
xfile.save('text2.xlsx')
```

Comment: But the method you suggested involved a different library, *openpyxl*, instead from what was asked, *xlsxwriter*.

Comment: ya because he asked for a solution " using xlswriter or any alternative " is that right?

Comment: @SagarMehta openpyxl does not support the old .xls file format, you can use xlrd to read the file, or convert it to the more recent .xlsx file format

Comment: @Ayser how about if I want to update an existing sheet (or multiple sheet) where each sheet is an entire pandas dataframe. How will make code look differently? Say I have 3 sheets, Sheet1, Sheet2, Sheet3, which exist and I want to update them with 3 pandas dataframes

Answer (score 2):

Note that openpyxl does not have a large toolbox for manipulating and editing images. Xlsxwriter has methods for images, but on the other hand cannot import existing worksheets...

I have found that this works for rows... 
I'm sure there's a way to do it for columns...

```
import openpyxl

oxl = openpyxl.load_workbook('File Loction Here')
xl = oxl.['SheetName']

x=0
col = "A"
row = x

while (row <= 100):
    y = str(row)
    cell = col + row
    xl[cell] = x
    row = row + 1
    x = x + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do by xlwings as well

```
import xlwings as xw
for book in xlwings.books:
    print(book)
```