# Write to Xlsx instead of CSV

Tags: python, export-to-excel, xlsx

I have script below that will write every night to a `CSV`. I would like to change that process and write directly to the `Xlsx` `Workbook` named NHL, `Sheet` Skater_Home in `col` AB `row` 1. I've read a couple other post's using the previously created csv to import into an existing `xlsx`. I can't seem to find whether or not I can just write to it directly without the `CSV` process.

```
import csv
import requests
import os

outfile = open("NHL_Skater_HOME_TOI.csv","a",newline='')
writer = csv.writer(outfile)
writer.writerow(["Player", "GameId", "EvTOI", "PpTOI", "ShTOI"])

req = requests.get('http://www.nhl.com/stats/rest/skaters?isAggregate=false&reportType=basic&isGame=true&reportName=timeonice&sort=[{%22property%22:%22playerName%22,%22direction%22:%22ASC%22}]&factCayenneExp=gamesPlayed%3E=1&cayenneExp=gameDate%3E=%222017-10-04%22%20and%20gameDate%3C=%222017-12-31%22%20and%20gameTypeId=2%20and%20gameLocationCode=%22H%22') 
data = req.json()['data']
for item in data:
    Player = item['playerName']
    GameId = item['gameId']
    EvTOI = item['evTimeOnIce']
    PpTOI = item['ppTimeOnIce']
    ShTOI = item['shTimeOnIce']


    print(Player, GameId, EvTOI, PpTOI, ShTOI)

    writer.writerow([Player, GameId, EvTOI, PpTOI, ShTOI])
outfile.close()
```

Comment: No, you don't need to use csv in order to write xlsx. You use xlsxwriter or openpyxl or similar libraries instead.

Comment: I have functions on the same sheet along with pivot tables. Will that overwrite them?

Comment: I haven't tested it, but generally I'd say no, if you don't touch those cells. The answer may vary by the library.

Comment: You can't Write to an existing Xlsx file with either of them that I've found.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18849535/