# Python how to export dataframes to two tabs in xlsx

Tags: python, xlsxwriter

I want to export dataframe C to an existing excel, saving it in a new tab.
I tried:

```
writer=pd.ExcelWriter(r'H:\test.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
C.to_excel(writer,sheet_name='c') 
writer.save()
```

(Notice: Excel test is an **existing** and previously saved Excel, with different tables A, B in tabs a, b, which I want to keep)

This code however deletes the existing excel and creates a new one with only the tab "c". I want to keep the existing tabs "a" and "b".

What is the right way?

ps: I tried  suggestion on link "How to save a new sheet in an existing excel file, using Pandas? "  as follows:

```
writer=pd.ExcelWriter(r'H:\C.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
y_pred_all2.to_excel(writer,sheet_name='cc')
writer.save()
writer.close()
from openpyxl import load_workbook
path=r'H:\C.xlsx'
book=load_workbook(path)
writer=pd.ExcelWriter(path, engine='xlsxwriter')
writer.book=book
C.to_excel(writer,sheet_name='returns')
```

This gives me error: AttributeError: 'Workbook' object has no attribute 'add_worksheet'

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to save a new sheet in an existing excel file, using Pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42370977/how-to-save-a-new-sheet-in-an-existing-excel-file-using-pandas)

Comment: I tried  suggestion on link "How to save a new sheet in an existing excel file, using Pandas? "  as follows:
    writer=pd.ExcelWriter(r'H:\C.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
    y_pred_all2.to_excel(writer,sheet_name='cc')
    writer.save()
    writer.close()

    from openpyxl import load_workbook
    path=r'H:\C.xlsx'
    book=load_workbook(path)
    writer=pd.ExcelWriter(path, engine='xlsxwriter')
    writer.book=book

    C.to_excel(writer,sheet_name='returns')  
 
This gives me error: AttributeError: 'Workbook' object has no attribute 'add_worksheet'

Comment: Do you have to use xlsxwriter? It sounds like this might be a limitation in that library, according to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18850144/10682164). According to pandas [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.ExcelWriter.html#pandas.ExcelWriter), the default for ExcelWriter is openpyxl which should be able to do this.

Comment: Indeed. Using writer=pd.ExcelWriter(path,engine='openpyxl') works. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Great, moved my comment to an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18850144/10682164) this is a limitation in the xlsxwriter engine. The pandas [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.ExcelWriter.html#pandas.ExcelWriter) show the default for ExcelWriter is to use openpyxl which should be able to do what you are looking for. If you want to be explicit about the engine being used, this should work:

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(path, engine='openpyxl')
```