# Python: TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, PosixPath

Tags: python, xlrd, pathlib

I am trying to run this python script which is trying to rename the xslx file using filename found in a column within the same xslx. (Original script found [Here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/posts/173948/revisions))

```
import os
from pathlib import Path

import xlrd

def rename_excel_files(path):
    path = Path(path)

    for filename in os.listdir(path):
        file_path = path.joinpath(filename)
        excel_file = xlrd.open_workbook(file_path)
        work_sheet = excel_file.sheet_by_index(1)
        dest_path = path.joinpath(work_sheet.cell_value(20, 0) + '.xlsx')
        os.replace(file_path, dest_path)

if __name__ == '__main__':
     rename_excel_files(r'/Users/User/OQC')
```

But getting the following error when running it python2:

```
  File "oqc_rename.py", line 18, in <module>
    rename_excel_files(r'/Users/User/OQC')
  File "oqc_rename.py", line 10, in rename_excel_files
    for filename in os.listdir(path):
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, PosixPath found
```

Updated: Error I get when I run python3:

```
 File "/Users/user/OQC/oqc_rename.py", line 19, in <module>
    rename_excel_files(r'/Users/user/OQC')
  File "/Users/user/OQC/oqc_rename.py", line 12, in rename_excel_files
    excel_file = xlrd.open_workbook(file_path)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/xlrd/__init__.py", line 148, in open_workbook
    bk = book.open_workbook_xls(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/xlrd/book.py", line 92, in open_workbook_xls
    biff_version = bk.getbof(XL_WORKBOOK_GLOBALS)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/xlrd/book.py", line 1278, in getbof
    bof_error('Expected BOF record; found %r' % self.mem[savpos:savpos+8])
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/xlrd/book.py", line 1272, in bof_error
    raise XLRDError('Unsupported format, or corrupt file: ' + msg)
xlrd.biffh.XLRDError: Unsupported format, or corrupt file: Expected BOF record; found b'\x00\x00\x00\x01Bud1'
```

Based on what I have searched, I think the issue might be that I have the file already open prior to renaming?
Confirmed xlsx file is not corrupt.
However, I am not sure how to get around this issue as I am a python noob.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which version of Python are you using? As of Python 3.6, `os.listdir` accepts `PosixPath` and other path-like objects. https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html

Comment: I was using 2.7.18 however, I did try 3.9 but got different sets of errors.

Comment: Without seeing what those errors are, it's hard tot be helpful. And for the future - when you're using Python 2, it's best not to tag your question as Python 3.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to write/update data into cells of existing XLSX workbook using xlsxwriter in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18849535/how-to-write-update-data-into-cells-of-existing-xlsx-workbook-using-xlsxwriter-i)

Answer (score 0):

`xlrd.open_workbook` is expecting a string, just represent the `Path` object as one and it should be happy

```
-xlrd.open_workbook(path)
+xlrd.open_workbook(str(path))
```

Do note that the official docs say non-`.xls` files are not supported:
https://pypi.org/project/xlrd/

> This library will no longer read anything other than .xls files. For alternatives that read newer file formats, please see http://www.python-excel.org/.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback!  After I did that, now I see the same error as running the script in python2 and python3.

Comment: Excellent-ish! Reads like the library simply doesn't support the new format, so another 3rd party library may work for you.