# PANDAS to Excel

Tags: excel, pandas

When saving DF to excel workbook, how can I pick specific cells for data to go into?

EX:

> 1      390.0
>  2     1390.0
>  3       94.0
>  4       50.0
>  5
> 1.0
>  6       70.0

1 would be in "A1"
2 would be in "A4"

etc

`df.to_excel("output.xlsx")` is there anything else I can add to this? or another way to do it?

thank you

Answer (score 0):

The task is not quite clear, but if it is to arrange the output lines with a certain gap, this can be done like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 'B': [390.0, 1390, 94, 50, 1, 70]})
gap = 2
df = df.groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x: pd.concat([x, pd.DataFrame([None]*gap)], ignore_index=True))
df.to_excel("output.xlsx", header=False, index=False, startrow=0, startcol=0)
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: Appreciate your input and apologize my question was vague. Forgive my lack of proper verbiage as I am merely an amateur at python, but: I have a dataframe that I did a groupby on. It left me with two columns. the first column is equal job location # 1. Second column is equal to amount of material being used. I wish to export this to an already made spreadsheet that has predefined spaces for job location and material required but are however empty.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @joeinreallife see the [solution with openpyxl](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34559425/15035314)