# How to read, modify and save an Excel file in Python?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, xml, xlsx

I wonder how can I read an Excel file using Python (xlsx extension), then **modify only rows 4,5,6,7,...** and save modified values in such format with **the same header** (yellow rows, picture, name of the columns - Description, Part number,...) and fixed columns width.

[image: Excel file]

When modifying the rows 4,5,6,7... I must use data frames. Now I'm doing this in this way:

1. Get the data from XML
2. Save the data to data frame.
3. Save df in file .csv.

```
def get_data_from_xml(path):
    #print(path)
    
    tree = ET.parse(path)
    root = tree.getroot()
    
    for Type in root.iter('Type'):
        PN = Type.get('name')
        #print(f"Part number: {PN}")
        DS = Type.get('Desc')
        #print(f"Description: {DS}")
        
        for Component in root.iter('Component'):
            CName = Component.get('name')
            if CName == 'Pos010_GearHousing':
                 for ComponentNo in Component.iter('ComponentNo'):
                    GH = ComponentNo.get('name')
                    #print(f"Gear Housing: {GH}")                   

            if CName == 'Pos058_PowerPack':
                 for ComponentNo in Component.iter('ComponentNo'):
                    PP = ComponentNo.get('name')
                    #print(f"Power Pack: {PP}")
                    
            if CName == 'Pos082_PedalInterface':
                 for ComponentNo in Component.iter('ComponentNo'):
                    PI = ComponentNo.get('name')
                    #print(f"Pedal Interface: {PI}")
                    
    #print(PN, GH, PP, DS, PI)
    return PN, GH, PP, DS, PI

pn_list = []
gh_list = []
pp_list = []
ds_list = []
pi_list = []

path = 'C:/Users/STJ2TW/Desktop/Files XML/'
for filename in os.listdir(path):
    if '.' not in filename:
        fullname = os.path.join(path, filename)
        #print(fullname)
        PN, GH, PP, DS, PI = get_data_from_xml(fullname)
        #print(pn, gh, pp)
        pn_list.append(PN)
        gh_list.append(GH)
        pp_list.append(PP)
        ds_list.append(DS)
        pi_list.append(PI)

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'Description': ds_list,
     'Part number': pn_list,
     'Gear Housing': gh_list,
     'Power Pack': pp_list,
     'Pedal Interface': pi_list,
    }) 

df = df.set_index('Description', drop = True)
df.to_csv("C:/Users/STJ2TW/Desktop/Files CSV/file.csv", sep=";")
df.head(10)
```

But instead of .csv file I should get the .xmls file with modified values.

**To sum up:**
First, I should read the XLSX file with formatting and header. Then read the values from another file - XML, put them into data frame and finally save data frame into this XLSX formatted file (on the picture).

How should I do this?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: @OldBill I have to work with XML, because this is what I get from the machine. I should use dataframes, but is there an easier way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [openpyxl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) to modify existing .xlsx files.
You can find a lot of information about this package online, and you can see an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18849535/how-to-write-update-data-into-cells-of-existing-xlsx-workbook-using-xlsxwriter-i).